# the_content filter is being applied to get_the_excerpt() too

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to hook `the_content` WordPress filter, to add some content to post. by using the function below

```
function _insert_in_post($content){
if (is_single() && !is_admin() && is_main_query()) {
return $content."blah blah";
}
}

add_filter('the_content', '_insert_in_post');
```

The content is being added, but I am having a problem that it's also being added to my related posts.

The related posts are using the `get_the_excerpt()` but still the_content is affecting them.

I want it to only apply this filter `the_content` to single post contents only.

I have tried using `is_main_query()` condition too, but in vain.

Can anyone help me in this regard please?

Comment: Try adding priority into your add_filter statement.

Comment: `is_main_query()` will not work here as the filter does not know in which context it is used

Comment: @zipkundan I tried priority too, but same result.